# Is it possible for a vector to have a non-identity basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let me explain what I mean... *Matrices transformations are commonly referred to as a change of basis*. Which I used to think meant that the **new vector used the new basis**, but then I realized I wasn't sure what this meant... Or if it was even possible.

If you assume the statement I have bolded above is true then that means in `Ax=b` b uses the basis vectors of A. But then you consider `Ib=b` which seems to imply that it actually uses the identity basis vectors.

It's embarrassing to ask such a naive question, but how are you supposed to describe this correctly? Does Ax use different basis vectors? But once you simplify to b it once again uses the identity basis vectors? Or should you just say that b is x represented with the basis vectors of A or something?

Comment: Matrices are always written with respect to some basis so you have to choose a basis first. You don't have to choose the canonical basis, which are the columns of the identity matrix, because any maximal set of linearly independent vectors is a basis. A change of basis likewise does not have to use the canonical basis either before or after the transformation. Also, not all matrices will represent a change of basis and whole classes of them will never represent a change of basis such as singular matrices.

Comment: @CyclotomicField "Matrices are always written with respect to some basis so you have to choose a basis first."
Given an arbitrary matrix how would you know what this basis is? Are you just referring to its column vectors or some meta-information?

Comment: You can't know what basis the matrix is using without being told. Tensor products are used to deal with this problem so you can discuss the transformations in a coordinate free manner and avoid the complications that come with choosing a basis.

Comment: Thanks, Is the basis that is being used a property of the vector space? I.e. are domain space and range space of a matrix different even if same dimension?

Comment: Dimension is a property of vector spaces, not matrices. The minimum number of basis vectors required is the dimension. Some vector spaces are infinite dimensional.

Comment: Let me clarify the second part: "I.e. are domain space and range space of a matrix different even if same dimension?" I meant: even if the range space has the same dimensionality of the domain space of a matrix, can they be different by 'having different basis vectors'?

Comment: No. The basis is a choice you make. It has nothing to do with the transformation at all.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I was asking about whether the spaces would be different under those conditions I wasn't directly asking about transformations.

Comment: It still demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of the material. I would strongly encourage you to work some problems in $\mathbb{R}^2$ involving different basis vectors without any transformations. That is, given two basis vectors express some other vector as a linear combination of the vectors. See how that expression changes when you use a different basis.